# How to get the description of web page without html tags?

Tags: python, django

Please help me out.. Am new to Python.
I tried to fetch the title, images and description of web page. I can fetch title and images but not description. When I fetch the description, it comes along with html tags.
I take this URL.
http://www.asianage.com/rss/37
I have tried the following code
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from os.path import basename, splitext
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def parser(request):
    source_txt=urllib.urlopen("http://www.asianage.com/rss/37")
    b=BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
    d={}
    for q in b.findAll('item'):
        arr1=[]
        for i in q.findAll('enclosure'):
            arr1.append(i['url'])
        d[q.title.string]=arr1
    return render(request,'link.html',{'arr':d})


def descrip(request):
    source_txt=urllib.urlopen("http://www.asianage.com/rss/37")
    b=BeautifulSoup(source_txt.read())
    arr1=[]
    for q in b.findAll('item'):
        for a in q.findAll('description'):
            arr1.append(a.string)
    return render(request,'desc.html',{'arr':arr1})
```

The first function is to fetch images and titles and display it respectively. The second function is to fetch the description.

I have written separate templates for both functions.
Template for first function:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:760px;margin:auto;border:1px solid #DCDCDC;">
{% for i,j,k in arr.items %}
<div style="width:250px;height:250px;float:left;border:1px solid #DCDCDC;">
    <div style="width:240px;height:180px;border:1px solid #DCDCDC;margin:auto;">
    <img src="{{j.0}}" style="width:240px;height:180px;"></div>
    <div style="width:240px;height:60px;border:1px solid #DCDCDC;margin:auto"><a href="/descrip">{{i}}</a></div>
</div>
{{k}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Template to access description.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% for m in arr %}
    <p>{{m}}</p><hr>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

For first function I am getting output correctly. But for description alone I am getting this output as follows(I put output for one iteration alone)

```
<div class="all-attached-images"><div style="width: 430px" class="image-attach-body"><a href="/i3jpg-603"><img src="http://www.asianage.com/sites/default/files/images/I3_6.jpg" alt="I3.jpg" title="I3.jpg" class="image image-content_image " width="430" height="317" /></a></div> </div><p>Malala Yousafzai hit back at claims that she has become a figure of the West, insisting she was proud to be a Pakistani.<br /> <!--break--><br /> The 16-year-old, who was shot by the Taliban for championing girls’ right to an education, claimed she retained the support of people in her homeland, and reiterated her desire to enter Pakistani politics.</p> <p>The activist was shot in the head on her school bus on October 9 last year for speaking out against the Taliban.</p> <p>She was flown for specialist care in Britain, where she has continued her education, while she has been feted and honoured in the West.</p> <p>On Thursday, she won the European Union’s prestigious Sakharov human rights prize, while US President Barack Obama welcomed her to the White House on Friday.</p> <p>Asked in a BBC television interview broadcast Sunday about some people in Pakistan thinking she was a “figure of the West” and “a Westerner now”, she said: “My father says that education is neither Eastern or Western. Education is education: it’s the right of everyone.</p> <p>“The thing is that the people of Pakistan have supported me. They don’t think of me as Western. I am a daughter of Pakistan and I am proud that I am a Pakistani.</p> <p>“On the day when I was shot, and on the next day, people raised the banners of ‘I am Malala’. They did not say ‘I am Taliban’.</p> <p>“They support me and they are encouraging me to move forward and to continue my campaign for girls’ education.”</p> <p>She highlighted the problem of education in the midst of the Syrian conflict.</p> <p>“We want to help every child in every country that we can,” she said.</p> <p>“We will start from Pakistan and Afghanistan and Syria now, especially because they are suffering the most and they are on the top that need our help.</p> <p>“Later on in my life I want to do politics and I want to become a leader and to bring the change in Pakistan.</p> <p>“I want to be a politician in Pakistan because I don’t want to be a politician in a country which is already developed.”</p>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try this (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) instead of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Jingo... but I would like to know how to do it using beautiful soup.. Could you help me?